# Intuition behind Stabilizer Tableau Simulation in Stim

Tags: stim

I'm looking through section 4 of the [Stim Paper](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-07-06-497/pdf/) and am having trouble understanding two points:

1. Why is it okay to insert Hadamards and random Xs at the beginning of computation and Hadamards? In the case of inserting CNOTs, it's clear that the measurement result will remain unchanged because of the all 0s input. But, inserting H, X (probabilistically) creates an entirely distinct circuit that could affect other observables; it's not obvious to me why the probabilities should stay the same.
2. Is it a typo in Section 4 to say that measuring $C Z_q C^{-1}$ at the start of time is the same as measuring $Z_q$ at the current time? Because isn't the relation $Z_q C |\psi \rangle= C Z_q' |\psi \rangle $ implies $Z_q' = C^{-1} Z_q C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it okay to insert Hadamards and random Xs at the beginning of computation and Hadamards?

If you're asked to measure a qubit in the X basis, and the qubit is in an eigenstate of Z, it will end up in $|-\rangle$ half the time and $|+\rangle$ half the time. One way to implement the transformation required by this measurement, from Z eigenstate to $|-\rangle$ or $|+\rangle$, is to randomize the Z value (with a randomly applied X gate) and then apply a Hadamard to switch the Z value into an X value.

That's what Stim is doing. It has reduced the requested measurement to this simple case, where an X basis measurement is happening to a single qubit in an eigenstate of Z. And then it solves that simple case. While reducing to the simple case, it's careful to only use operations that preserve the state of the system. But once you're in the simple case, you can start making the needed changes required by the requested measurement.

> Is it a typo in Section 4

Honestly I can never remember which order the C's go in.

Comment: Maybe this is a pedantic question but re your second paragraph -- why is it the case that we can make these H, X modifications that would actually affect the state? I don't understand the math behind this -- some equations would help, I think.

Sorry if this is really obvious!

Comment: @C.Kang because if your current state is |0> and you measure in the X basis, the state must change.

Comment: I think I understand and the equation to back it up is the following:

$1/2 (I + Z) C | \psi \rangle = C 1/2 (I + Z') | \psi \rangle$
so, like you wrote in the paper, a measurement at the end of the $Z$ operator is equivalent to a measurement at the beginning of the $Z'$ operator, and in this case the operator would be an $X$ projection; that's why measurement can be performed at the beginning and propagated through the system.